# nfs mount fails due to same file handle

Tags: linux, nfs

In /etc/exports:

```
/tmp/test    *(rw)
```

`/dev/sda1` (ext4 filesystem) is mounted in `/tmp/test`

command to mount nfs:

`mount -o vers=3 $HOST:/tmp/test $NFS_DIR`

(where HOST is IP of nfs server, NFS_DIR is local mount point on client)

The first time, nfs mount success. And then I did unmount.

Then I command out the entry in /etc/exports(no nfs export), and do `exportfs -r`.

Then I uncomment the /tmp/test entry in /etc/exports (same as before), and do `exportfs -r` again

And I mount the nfs share by using the same command. But this time, the mount will hang and time out.

However, when I check the log of nfs, I got this:

```
/tmp and /tmp/test have same filehandle for *, using first
qword_eol: fflush failed: errno 22 (Invalid argument)
Cannot export /tmp, possibly unsupported filesystem or fsid= required"
```

The error complaining about export /tmp make sense because it is tmpfs.

But why /tmp and /tmp/test has to same file handle?

I know the issue is cause by /tmp and /tmp/test having the same file handle, so nfs returns the first one which is /tmp. What I want to exported is /tmp/test (ext4 fs), not /tmp (tmpfs).

The issue get solved by restart rpc.mountd.

1. why /tmp /tmp/test get the same file handle?
2. why restart rpc.mountd solves the issue?
3. how to solve this issue without restart rpc.mounts?

Comment: Don't mount exported filesystems under `/tmp`.

Comment: why? the nfs export is /tmp/test which is mounted by /dev/sda1 of ext4 filesystem. (df /tmp/test gives /dev/sda1 ext4)

Comment: Because most distributions have automated jobs that spider down `/tmp` cleaning things up.  The OS rather assumes that things mounted under `/tmp` are disposable, especially if old; you can lose a *lot* of a filesystem that way.

Comment: I am working on embedded linux, just kernel  + uboot + rootfs + device tree (not any distribution), I am sure that there is no job that clean up /tmp, /tmp only get clean up when reboot. And there is some reason why we mount it under /tmp, in short, we want some of these mount get cleaned when reboot. I learned what is a file handle, and /tmp and /tmp/test should never get the same file handle.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it is the bug in nfs-utils itself. And this bug get fixed in version 1.3.3. I also tried using nfs-utls 1.3.2, but the issue is still there. Using nfs-utils 1.3.3 will fix this issue.

Comment: Can you provide some more information on the bug that you are referring to?

Comment: See: https://svwh.dl.sourceforge.net/project/nfs/nfs-utils/1.3.3/1.3.3-Changelog